# dwm.exe taking all GPU resource when opening chromium based apps on multi monitor setup

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, gpu, chromium, dwm

I am using Lenovo ThinkPad P15s Gen 2. This laptop has two GPUs:

1. Intel Iris Xe Graphics and
2. NVIDIA T500.

I plugged this laptop to Lenovo thunderbolt 4 docking station. I connected two monitors into it, one 4K and the other is not. Every now and then, my whole Windows10 based computer got very2 slow. To the point that I can't do anything on it. When I check the task manager, it turns out that Desktop Window Manager (dwm.exe) and/or "Client Server Runtime Process" (csrss.exe) are the culprit. They are taking all 100% the GPU resources (on the Intel Iris one, the NVIDIA one often times are just left being idle).

[image]

I notice those 2 processes only eat up all the GPU resources when I use any Chromium based application (Chrome, Edge, Ms Teams, VSCode etc). Even if Just use let's say Chrome and watch Youtube short and not opening any other things, it could go on to this voracious episode. If I close any Chromium based app, the GPU resource usage will gradually return back to normal after about 1-2 minutes. Same thing will happen if I just unplug my laptop from the docking station. If the laptop is not being plugged to the docking station in the first place, the issue actually never comes out.

I called Lenovo tech support about it and they just asked me to upgrade (reflash) the firmware of the docking station. I did that but it does not help. I also updated all the graphic drivers in my laptop and this also does not help.  I guess it's either Microsoft's fault with their dwm.exe/CSRP or Chromium's fault in how they are letting web application consume GPUs. Any idea how should I investigate deeper?